# How to set local notifications on Swift(Xcode) on Background App Refresh?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am currently developing an iOS app in which notifications are necessary. Currently, I am storing a html string in a User Default object:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(transcriptHTML, forKey: "transcript")
```

In order to get the transcriptHTML I used Alamo Fire to post login information and get necessary html. I want to use the IOS Background app refresh every 5-10 minutes to detect changes in the transcriptHTML(by comparing the userDefault  Object html to the new transcript html I get from the net).

However, I am unfamiliar with IOS Background app refresh and also the notification process in general. Any help or advice on how to tackle the problem would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Background app refresh won't execute that often. It will more likely trigger a few times every 24 hours at most.  Polling is a bad approach. It isn't battery or network friendly.  This is a task that should be delegated to some cloud server that can send a push notification to your app when required.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Apple IOS developer website for more information.

https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

The PushKit framework and Push API will be really useful in your development. I have experience with this software and was able to create a successful chat application on IOS platforms. I have more than 10 years of experience with IOS app development, so let me know if you need further information.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with push kit. Can you tell the best source to learn this framework ?

Comment: PushKit is limited to VoIP apps. You can use regular push notifications.